# JFrog Artifactory after upgrade to 6.6.5, from 5.6, is not authenticating internal users during mvn build

Tags: artifactory

I upgraded artifactory-pro from 5.6 to 6.6. It's configured to use AD for authentication. There are a few internal users, mostly for CI/CD. It did no import all the groups/permissions, did import users. I added the missing permissions and groups. But builds are failing with 403 Download request ... is forbidden. This is for internal and LDAP users. These users can login to the UI. Also, the internal users are only authenticated with ldap, does not look at internal user data.

When I tried a test import/export last month it was working.
I have tried the export/import process 3 times. I validated the repositories are imported correct.

Comment: Which users can't authenticate, external or internal?

Comment: Both get the 403 using mvn, ivy, sbt and rest.

Comment: Still getting 403.  I have installed with version 6.5.2. Now it says 'USERNAME" not found in 'LDAPNAME'.  I thought artifactory was supposed to check internal if not found in external user store.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that 6.6 introduced separate permissions on BuildInfo objects. Please set those permissions manually (as they are new), and it should solve the issue. More details in [Artifactory 6.6 release notes](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Artifactory6.6).